# Testing Sharepoint 2010 Beta

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Virtual Machine with MOSS 2007 (Enterprise), VS2008 and SQL 2005.

I want to start exploring 2010. I need to know what I need to get started.

Can I donwload 2010 beta from Microsoft Site? Can I just install it without any conflicts with existing setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can download the beta from MSDN.

It only supports 64 bit. You should provide yourself at least 6GB of RAM for decent performance. You can install it on Win 7, Windows Server 2008 SP2, or Windows Server 2008 R2. You can use SQL Express or install SQL Server 2008 separately. If you use SQL Server, you will need to install CU2.

Comment: Thanks!. Looks good...Wait!!!!!! 6 GIG of RAM??? I have 4 Gig on my machine and give 2.5 GIG for VM, but thats it...

Comment: Guess I will be working with MOSS-2007 for a while :(...

Comment: Yeah, I recommend having 6GB of RAM, but 4 will work, just not all that well. This was a big issue for us at first as well.

Comment: I've got a VM running just fine with 3GB, W008R2 Std, MSDE install of 2010 but visual studio is only installed on host which makes debugging a little more difficult (have to use remote debugging and its not very good on 64bit)